# Django encoding in Danish project

Tags: django, encoding

I'm getting sick of encoding problems in my Django projects!

I just converted a project from being "latin-1" to be "utf-8" due to some database problems! my database must obviously be UTF-8 ..

Convertering of HTML pages went fine but when I do a search as before ?q=t%E6st then write it just tï¿½st in the database .. why?

What encoding is best to use in a django project?

Comment: What database are you using? Did you set up the default encoding for tables?

Comment: I use: postgresql ... How do I set a default encoding for tables? .. DB: DBNAME | DBNAME| UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |

Comment: Does encoding problems apply to newly inserted data?

Comment: yep :( this is the data from the database : tï¿½st   on the field: search_str

Comment: You should check for django folder at /Lib/site-packages/django. Everything need to be utf-8. I always use easyeclipse for python and set up my projects utf-8 and used at first line of any of the project files the following code: `# coding=UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

Django is made to natively support Unicode data anywhere. It is recommended that you use UTF-8 or UTF-16 as your encoding for your django project as latin1 could give problems sometimes.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#creating-the-database